# npm install code error

Tags: angularjs, node.js

So all I am trying to do is start the tutorial for angular but I am having a biggest pain trying to install all of the programs to get going. When I put in the code "npm install" it gives me this:

```
$ npm install
Error: EPERM, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\angular-phonecat'
at Error (native)

Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
at Error (native)
at emit (events.js:87:13)
at cleanupSync (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
fs-write-stream-atomic\index.js:46:42)
at WriteStream.emit (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mod
ules\fs-write-stream-atomic\index.js:53:12)
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1777:12)
at OpenReq.Req.done (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mod
ules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:141:5)
at OpenReq.done (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:61:22)
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:99:15)
```

If someone could help that would be awesome I just want to get started on Angular.

Comment: npm install to install bower, karma, protractor, and http-server or something or other

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install to `C:\Program Files (x86)`, which needs extra permissions. Either start your shell with admin rights, or better install it somewhere else.

Comment: exactly how do I "start my shell with admin rights"? nooby here

Comment: How to [start a shell with admin rights](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but it _REALLY_ is a better idea to install your tutorial somewhere else than `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Running a shell with admin rights could screw your system. For example I use `C:\users\mles\documents\nodejs` as my base path for nodejs projects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to disable AntiVirus software on Windows, and then try again.

https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/19

Comment: Where is Phantom js mentioned?

Comment: I don't believe it is. Different packages can experience the same errors though, and from what I saw EPERM often has to do with extracting, which can be prevented by an AntiVirus software on Windows.